# Column size reduced while restoring oracle database

Tags: oracle, dump

I have an Oracle database restored on a server and found an unexpected issue. As per the client a specific columns holds 122 values while I could only fetch 32. When I checked the column length it was 255 which was not correct as it should be more. Is it possible that somehow while restoring the database, the size of column is reduced to default size and it truncated the data from where it exceeded limit ? The column was of `VARCHAR2` datatype and its size I am getting is `VARCHAR2(255)`. I cannot get to know the size of client side as i don't have access but I am sure it will be much greater as he shared screenshot of the data and it was more.
Can anyone guide ?

Comment: most likely you restored a different version of the application/data model...there's not a scenario where you have a database backup with a table defined with a column of say varchar2(4000) and the db goes, no, that should be 255. The closest to this would be where you have a column defined as varchar2(255 char) and it gets done as varchar2(255 byte) and many characters can take 2-4 bytes per character, thereby reducing the effective number of characters that column can now store

Comment: What mechanism was used to restore the database? Are you talking about `rman`, or an export/import, or generated insert scripts (and perhaps DDL)? How/why do you have multiple values - presumably you mean you're storing comma-separated strings representing multiple values (which is a bad data model); or do you actually mean you originally had 122 *rows* with one value each and now only have 32?